# What's the command to disable stylesheets in vimperator?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, css, vimperator

What's the command to disable the stylesheet for the current web page with vimperator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:emenu View.Page Style.No Style
```

Comment: it's so long, is there a way to shorten it?